# Python ElementTree won't convert non-breaking spaces when using UTF-8 for output

Tags: python, xml, encoding, elementtree

I'm trying to parse, manipulate, and output HTML using Python's ElementTree:

```
import sys
from cStringIO  import StringIO
from xml.etree  import ElementTree as ET
from htmlentitydefs import entitydefs

source = StringIO("""<html>
<body>
<p>Less than &lt;</p>
<p>Non-breaking space &nbsp;</p>
</body>
</html>""")

parser = ET.XMLParser()
parser.parser.UseForeignDTD(True)
parser.entity.update(entitydefs)
etree = ET.ElementTree()

tree = etree.parse(source, parser=parser)
for p in tree.findall('.//p'):
    print ET.tostring(p, encoding='UTF-8')
```

When I run this using Python 2.7 on Mac OS X 10.6, I get:

```
<p>Less than &lt;</p>

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bar.py", line 20, in <module>
    print ET.tostring(p, encoding='utf-8')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1120, in tostring
    ElementTree(element).write(file, encoding, method=method)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 815, in write
    serialize(write, self._root, encoding, qnames, namespaces)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 931, in _serialize_xml
    write(_escape_cdata(text, encoding))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1067, in _escape_cdata
    return text.encode(encoding, "xmlcharrefreplace")
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xa0 in position 19: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I thought that specifying "encoding='UTF-8'" would take care of the non-breaking space character, but apparently it doesn't. What should I do instead?

Answer (score 7):

0xA0 is a latin1 character, not a unicode character and the value of p.text in the loop is a str and not unicode, that means that in order to encode it in utf-8 it must first be converted  by Python implicitly into a unicode string (i.e. using decode). When it is doing this it assumes ascii since it wasn't told anything else. 0xa0 is not a valid ascii character, but it is a valid latin1 character.

The reason you have latin1 characters instead of unicode characters is because entitydefs is a mapping of names to latin1 encode strings. You need the unicode code point which you can get from htmlentitydef.name2codepoint

The version below should fix it for you:

```
import sys
from cStringIO  import StringIO
from xml.etree  import ElementTree as ET
from htmlentitydefs import name2codepoint

source = StringIO("""<html>
<body>
<p>Less than &lt;</p>
<p>Non-breaking space &nbsp;</p>
</body>
</html>""")

parser = ET.XMLParser()
parser.parser.UseForeignDTD(True)
parser.entity.update((x, unichr(i)) for x, i in name2codepoint.iteritems())
etree = ET.ElementTree()

tree = etree.parse(source, parser=parser)
for p in tree.findall('.//p'):
    print ET.tostring(p, encoding='UTF-8')
```

Comment: This is the correct answer! To put it more concisely, `htmlentitydefs.entitydefs` is bad. It’s causing byte strings to be added into your ElementTree where there should only be unicode strings. And unfortunately the error doesn’t surface until later.

Answer (score 4):

XML only defines `&lt;`, `&gt;`, `&apos;`, `&quot;` and `&amp;`. `&nbsp;` and others come from HTML. So you have a couple of choices.

1. You can change your source to use numeric entities, like `&#160;` or `&#xA0;` both of which are equivalent to `&nbsp;`.
2. You can use a DTD which defines those values.

There is some useful information (it is written about XSLT, but XSLT is written using XML, so the same applies) at the [XSLT FAQ](http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/nbsp.html).

---

The question appears now to include a stack trace; that changes things. Are you sure that the string is in `UTF-8`? If it resolves to the single byte `0xA0`, then it isn't `UTF-8` but more likely `cp1252` or `iso-8859-1`.

Comment: The problem isn't on input: the UseForeignDTD trick works fine for that.  The problem is on output: the text in memory contains 0xA0, which I expected would be converted to its UTF-8 representation by ET.tostring (since I said 'encoding="UTF-8"').

Answer (score 3):

Your `&nbsp;` is being converted to '\xa0' which is the default (ascii) encoding for a nonbreaking space (the UTF-8 encoding is '\xc2\xa0'.) The line

```
'\xa0'.encode('utf-8')
```

results in a UnicodeDecodeError, because the default codec, ascii, only works up to 128 characters and ord('\xa0') = 160. Setting the default encoding to something else, i.e.:

```
import sys
reload(sys)  # must reload sys to use 'setdefaultencoding'
sys.setdefaultencoding('latin-1')

print '\xa0'.encode('utf-8', "xmlcharrefreplace")
```

should solve your problem.

Answer (score -1):

HTML is not the same as XML, so tags like `&nbsp;` will not work. Ideally, if you are trying to pass that information via XML, you could first xml-encode the above data, so it would look something like this:

```
<xml>
<mydata>
&lt;htm&gt;
&lt;body&gt;
&lt;p&gt;Less than &amp;lt;&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p&gt;Non-breaking space &amp;nbsp;&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;/body&gt;
&lt;/html&gt;
</mydata>
</xml>
```

And then after parsing the XML you can HTML-unencode the string.

Comment: The problem isn't on input: the UseForeignDTD trick works fine for that.  The problem is on output: the text in memory contains 0xA0, which I expected would be converted to its UTF-8 representation by ET.tostring (since I said 'encoding="UTF-8"').

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem you have here is not with your nbsp entity but with your print statement.

Your error is:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xa0 in position 19: ordinal not in range(128)

I think this is because you're taking a utf-8 string (from `ET.tostring(p, encoding='utf-8')`) and trying to echo it out in a ascii terminal.  So Python is implicitly converting that string to unicode then converting it again to ascii. Although nbsp *can* be represented directly in utf-8, it *cannot* be represented directly in ascii. Hence the error.

Try saving the output to a file instead and seeing if you get what you expect.

Alternatively, try `print ET.toString(p, encoding='ascii')`, which should cause ElementTree to use numeric character entities to represent anything that can't be represented with ascii.

Comment: Saving the output to a file has no effect: if I open a file using "output = open('temp.txt', 'w')" and then use "output.write(ET.tostring(p, encoding='ascii'))", I get the same error.